# Adding elements to an empty ArrayList<T>

Tags: java, arraylist, sonarlint

I am adding objects to an ArrayList that is initialized as null inside a for each loop, but SonarLint is giving me a "NullPointerException" could be thrown when I try to add each object. Why is this error being pointed out?

```
public List<SatelliteData> getData()
  {
    SatelliteData satellite;
    ArrayList<SatelliteData> satelliteList = null;

    try(FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(satelliteOutputFile))
    {
      TLEParser parsedFile = new TLEParser();
      List<TLE> tleList = parsedFile.readFile(file);

      for (TLE tle : tleList)
      {
        satellite = new SatelliteData(tle);
        satellite.collectSatelliteData();

        satelliteList.add(satellite); //A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "satelliteList" is nullable here
      }

    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
      LOGGER.error("IO Exception: " +  ex);
      notifyTheObservers("IO Exception: " + ex);
    }

    return satelliteList;
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Why is this error being pointed out?", are you not expecting a NPE here?

Comment: Because you never initialize `satelliteList`.

Comment: NullPointerException can be thrown because you are trying to call methods on a null object. You need to actually create `satelliteList` somewhere like `satelliteList = new ArrayList<SatelliteData>();`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't call member methods on variables that have been initialized to nothing/null.

In this case you have

```
ArrayList<SatelliteData> satelliteList = null;
```

This variable does not have any memory allocated to it.

> At this point your computer knows : *Okay there exists something
>   called satelliteData* but it actually *doesn't know where it is?*

Calling add() method on it, is likely to throw a **NullPointerException** because this variable is a reference that is pointing to null/nothing.

To overcome this, You need to initialize the variable like this :

```
ArrayList<SatelliteData> satelliteList = new ArrayList<SatelliteData>();
```

> At this point your computer created that satteliteData and knows
>   exactly where it exists hence it can happily operate upon it.

This will allocate some memory to this variable and now it has its own methods you can call.

Comment: The variable is not uninitialized though, it is initialized to null. If it wasn't initialized by the time it was called, the compiler would complain before even running

Comment: Javier, Done Thanks